# How to Pass a PHP Variable to a MySql Query to Create an Excel Document Download

Tags: mysql, ajax, excel, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from one PHP page to another PHP page, which will trigger an Excel download.  However, I cannot figure out how to pass the variable and still have the download trigger.  I understand that my PHP page which creates the Excel file cannot have any variables passed to it, or the download will not trigger.

For example, I would like to do the following (very simple example):

variable.php

```
<?php
$date = '2012-02-15';
echo '<input type="text" id="date" value="'.$date.'"/>';
echo '<span onclick="excelDownload()">Click</span>';
?>
```

passing.js

```
function excelDownload(str)
{
  Ajax... 
  var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
  var queryString = "?date=" + date;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "excel.php" + queryString, true);
  Ajax....
}
```

excel.php

```
<?php
Connect to database... 
$date = $_GET['date'];
$file = "Names: ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Something WHERE date_field = '$date'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$file.= $data['names']." ";
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=names.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print $file;
?>
```

Unfortunately, the $_GET[date'] variable causes the excel.php to not download.  I have been able to get away with writing static MySql queries within the excel.php page, so I do not have to pass any variables.  However, I now have the need to create dynamic excel downloads, but I am not strong enough in php to figure out my options.  On a side note, I use Ajax and do not utilize "submit".  Will this be a problem?

Comment: _I understand that my PHP page which creates the Excel file cannot have any variables passed to it, or the download will not trigger._ Why? Also, are you getting any error or something?

Comment: I am not getting any error, instead a new window will appear, after I trigger the onclick event, and the download prompt does not execute.  I read somewhere that the php page with the excel headers cannot have any data going into it, for the download to trigger.  If I wrote '2012-02-15' into the mysql query, instead of passing  variable to it, the download prompt will trigger.

Comment: To reiterate my question: How do you pass a variable to run a MySql query, and then trigger a download of an Excel file with the MySql query results?  My problem is the fact that you cannot output anything before the PHP headers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem and wanted to share my findings to close out this question.  Basically, I should have been more detailed in my question.  My Ajax function needed some tweaking so that the variable would pass and allow the headers to trigger a download.

I was using the following in my Ajax function:

```
Ajax...
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
  {
   //nothing to allow download to trigger
  }
}
var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
var queryString = "?date=" + date;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "excel.php" + queryString, true):
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

However, I should have used this:

```
Ajax...
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
  {
   window.location = "excel.php" + queryString;
  }
}
var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
var queryString = "?date=" + date;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "excel.php" + queryString, true):
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

While I was thinking my problem had to do with output before header(), the real issue was passing the variable.

Comment: Something seems wrong here.. window.location will redirect your page to the specified URL. That is a non-ajax request will be fired. You don't seem to be using the response from AJAX in anyway...